# c# entity framework - blazor application - ChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, tracking

I'm using the entity framework in a blazor application. My context is scoped.

I have a tracked entity with a modified property but I cancel the modification. This entity is still tracked and the tracker still contains the modification cancelled.

If I use savechanges the canceled modification will be propagated in the database.

How to avoid this? (change the state of the entity so that it is not modified?)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Which Blazor?  How is the ctx scoped? How do you cancel?

Comment: Blazor Server do not support Scoped context, because it do not create `scope` automatically. You have to use `IDbContextFactory`.

Comment: My application is similar to a desktop application. I will need to keep the same context while using several different services.

Comment: Even in desktop applications keeping the DbContext open longer than for one method is incorrect.

Comment: `dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` ?

Comment: As pointed out by @phillipFrank in his comment on the answer provided, You should be using a DbContext Factory and unit of work contexts.  Using a single long lived context in an SPA Async context is not only bad practice, but will lead to all sorts of issues as your application grows.  Search "blazor dbcontextfactory" for lots of resources and information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

DbContext is a class that is designed to be extremely short lived.

You should create a new DbContext for every operation (or a batch of operations) using IDbContextFactory and dispose it right after it. If you do not you just have introduced into your code at best a memory leak, at worst exactly the unwanted and hard to debug behavior you are writing about.

If you need some optimization you can introduce DbContext pooling to clean the entity tracking by disposing the context, but keeping the underlying DbConnection instances alive (making the connection is the slow part)

Comment: For example I have a client who contains invoices.
I upload the client without savechanges and in my razor page I include a link to their invoices.

I started a modification on my client and in the invoices page I modify an invoice and I save I no longer have the same context and therefore I lose my client's tracking and therefore I lose my modification.

Comment: Your problem is not with DbContext, but rather with completely incorrect application architecture that is not supported by current implementation of DbContext.